# Which package do I have to use?

Tags: errors

When I compile that in latex, it is not working. Which package do I have to use here? Generally, could anyone is able to fix that file in such a way that it works in Latex?

```
In general, an isometry of $\mathbb R^2$ is a composition of a rotation, a reflection, and a translation.  Every isometry either preserves orientation (so that clockwise loops map to clockwise loops) or reverses it (so that clockwise maps to counterclockwise). In this case, we just have a composition of a translation and a rotation:
\begin{array}{rccc}
x & \mapsto & ax-by & \mapsto & ax-by + c \\
y & \mapsto & bx+ay & \mapsto & bx+ay + d \\[6pt]
& \uparrow & & \uparrow \\
& \text{rotation} & & \text{translation} \\
& (\text{where } \\
& a^2+b^2 \\
& =1.)
\end{array}
In the above, if you find $a$, then you have $b=\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}$ so you've got $b$ except for $\text{“}\pm\text{''}$.
Find two particular points whose images you know: thus $(x_0,y_0)$ maps to $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ maps to $(x_3,y_3)$, and plug them in to the the system of equations above (including $a^2+b^2=1$), and solve for $a,b,c,d$.
```

Comment: Can you please make your code snippet compilable? What does "not working" mean? Please explain better ...  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array` has to be used in math not text, and you have used 5 columns in the array but only declared 4, then you need `amsfonts` (for `\mathbb`) and `amsmath` (or `amstext` for `\text`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\begin{document}
In general, an isometry of $\mathbb R^2$ is a composition of a rotation, a reflection, and a translation.  Every isometry either preserves orientation (so that clockwise loops map to clockwise loops) or reverses it (so that clockwise maps to counterclockwise). In this case, we just have a composition of a translation and a rotation:
\[\begin{array}{rcccc}
x & \mapsto & ax-by & \mapsto & ax-by + c \\
y & \mapsto & bx+ay & \mapsto & bx+ay + d \\[6pt]
& \uparrow & & \uparrow \\
& \text{rotation} & & \text{translation} \\
& (\text{where } \\
& a^2+b^2 \\
& =1.)
\end{array}\]
In the above, if you find $a$, then you have $b=\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}$ so you've got $b$ except for $\text{“}\pm\text{''}$.
Find two particular points whose images you know: thus $(x_0,y_0)$ maps to $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ maps to $(x_3,y_3)$, and plug them in to the the system of equations above (including $a^2+b^2=1$), and solve for $a,b,c,d$.
\end{document}
```